# How to count elements in dictionary using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, count

This is my Dict:

```
{'com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.LegislatorProfileFragment': ['Move Attribute']}
{'com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.LegislatorProfileFragment': ['Move Method']}
{'com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.LegislatorProfileFragment': ['Move Method']}
{'com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.LegislatorProfileFragment': ['Move Method']}
{'com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.LegislatorProfileFragment': ['Move Method']}
{'com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.LegislatorProfileFragment': ['Move Method']}
{'com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.LegislatorProfileFragment': ['Move Method']}
{'com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.LegislatorProfileFragment': ['Move Method']}
```

The key is the name of the class and the value is the refactoring type, in this exemple I have only one class and it contains 1 Move Attribute and 7 Move Method.

I used this code to calculate the number of refactoring type in each class

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('output2.csv', sep=',')
df1 = df[['RefactoringType','RefactoringDetail']]
df1['Detail']=df.RefactoringDetail.str.extract(r'[C|c]lass\s*([^ ]*)')
del df1['RefactoringDetail']

#this part generate the map 
my_map={}
for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
  my_map[df1['Detail'][i]] = []
  my_map[df1['Detail'][i]].append(df1['RefactoringType'][i])
  print(my_map)

#define all refactoring operations  
all_refactorings=['Extract Superclass','Move Attribute','Extract Method','Inline Method','Rename Method','Move Method','Rename Package','Move Attribute','Pull Up Method','Pull Up Attribute','Push Down Method','Push Down Attribute','Move Class','Rename Class','Move And Rename Class','Extract And Move Method','Move Source Folder','Change Package','Extract Variable','Rename Attribute','Move and Rename Attribute','Replace Variable with Attribute','Replace Attribute ','Merge Variable','Merge Parameter','Merge Attribute','split Variable','split Parameter','Split Attribute','Extract Interface']
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Class'] + all_refactorings )

for class_name in my_map :
  new_row = {ref:0 for ref in all_refactorings} 
  new_row['Class'] = class_name
  for ref_type in my_map[class_name] :
    new_row[ref_type] += 1 
  newdf=newdf.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
newdf
```

and it return for me:

```
Class   Extract Superclass  Move Attribute  Extract Method  Inline Method   Rename Method   Move Method Rename Package  Move Attribute  Pull Up Method  Pull Up Attribute   Push Down Method    Push Down Attribute Move Class  Rename Class    Move And Rename Class   Extract And Move Method Move Source Folder  Change Package  Extract Variable    Rename Attribute    Move and Rename Attribute   Replace Variable with Attribute Replace Attribute   Merge Variable  Merge Parameter Merge Attribute split Variable  split Parameter Split Attribute Extract Interface
com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.Le...   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I could not foud where is the error It should give me 7 Move Method and 1 Move Attribute!

Any help please

Comment: Have you tried using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: It seems like you have 8 dictionaries instead of one. Or at least looks like a dictionaries of dictionaries. How are you generating "my_map" ?

Comment: @ Ricardo Rivaldo I edit my answer to show how i genrate the map

Comment: @ AdamGold  Yes I tried collections.Counter and it return the same result !

Comment: Now adding a read from CSV is useless if you don't supply the CSV. What code generates the map _from the 8 dictionaries you posted_?

Comment: It would be clearer if you could show a sample of the csv file. Also, is `df1.value_counts()` maybe what you are looking for?

Comment: Should my_map be a list instead , since each time you do "'com.sunlightlabs.android.congress.fragments.LegislatorProfileFragment': something" you redefine the value for the key, so, you end with a one entry dictionarie (the last defined value for the key).

Comment: @ I add a comment to show the part that generate the map